# How to add ROW grandtotals/substotals in a Julia DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Let's say I have a df looking like this one, where I have multiple categorical values and several variables:

```
df = wsv"""
region product year prod cons
US     apples  2010 1    2
US     appels  2011 3    4
US     banana  2010 5    6
US     banana  2011 7    8
EU     apples  2010 9    10
EU     appels  2011 11   12
EU     banana  2010 13   14
EU     banana  2011 15   16
"""
```

How can I transform it to have category totals/subtotals as new rows, i.e.

```
df2 = wsv"""
index  prod  cons
US     16    20
apples 4     6
2010   1     2
2011   3     4
banana 12    14
2010   5     6
2011   7     8
EU     48    52
apples 20    22
2010   9     10
2011   11    12
banana 28    30
2010   13    14
2011   15    16
"""
```

This is often useful, after proper formatting (e.g. totals in bold..), to report data, as many reports use actually this kind of structure..

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `by` to achieve something similar:

```
df2 = by(df, :region) do sub1
      t = DataFrame(product=NA, year=NA, prod=sum(sub1[:prod]), cons=sum(sub1[:cons]))
      sub1mod = by(sub1, [:region,:product]) do sub2
        t2 = DataFrame(year=NA, prod=sum(sub2[:prod]), cons=sum(sub2[:cons]))
        t3 = vcat(t2,sub2)
      end
      t2 = vcat(t,sub1mod)
end
delete!(df2,[:region_1,:region_2,:product_1])
```

Out:

```
14×5 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ region │ product  │ year │ prod │ cons │
├─────┼────────┼──────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ "EU"   │ NA       │ NA   │ 48   │ 52   │
│ 2   │ "EU"   │ "apples" │ NA   │ 20   │ 22   │
│ 3   │ "EU"   │ "apples" │ 2010 │ 9    │ 10   │
│ 4   │ "EU"   │ "apples" │ 2011 │ 11   │ 12   │
│ 5   │ "EU"   │ "banana" │ NA   │ 28   │ 30   │
│ 6   │ "EU"   │ "banana" │ 2010 │ 13   │ 14   │
│ 7   │ "EU"   │ "banana" │ 2011 │ 15   │ 16   │
│ 8   │ "US"   │ NA       │ NA   │ 16   │ 20   │
│ 9   │ "US"   │ "apples" │ NA   │ 4    │ 6    │
│ 10  │ "US"   │ "apples" │ 2010 │ 1    │ 2    │
│ 11  │ "US"   │ "apples" │ 2011 │ 3    │ 4    │
│ 12  │ "US"   │ "banana" │ NA   │ 12   │ 14   │
│ 13  │ "US"   │ "banana" │ 2010 │ 5    │ 6    │
│ 14  │ "US"   │ "banana" │ 2011 │ 7    │ 8    │
```