# How to collapse data with duplicate timestamps in Julia `DataFrame`

Tags: julia

I have a `DataFrame` object looking as follows:

```
| Row | timestamp           | price | volume |
|-----|---------------------|-------|--------|
| 1   | 2011-08-14T14:14:40 | 10.40 | 0.779  |
| 2   | 2011-08-14T15:15:17 | 10.40 | 0.101  |
| 3   | 2011-08-14T15:15:17 | 10.40 | 0.316  |
| ... | ................... | ..... | .....  |
```

The `timestamps` are non-unique, so I cannot convert to a `TimeArray` before resolving this. How can I collapse duplicate `timestamps`, taking the mean of the prices and the sum of the volumes?

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [by](https://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/split_apply_combine.html):

```
df = DataFrame(
  cat = ["a", "b", "c","a"],
  prices = [1,2,3,4],
  vol    = [10,20,30,40],
)

df2 = by(df, :cat) do sub
      t = DataFrame(prices=mean(sub[:prices]), vol=sum(sub[:vol]))
end

df2

3×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ cat │ prices │ vol │
├─────┼─────┼────────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ "a" │ 2.5    │ 50  │
│ 2   │ "b" │ 2.0    │ 20  │
│ 3   │ "c" │ 3.0    │ 30  │
```

If you have to make some totals by day/months/etc you may be interested also in [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591630/how-to-add-row-grandtotals-substotals-in-a-julia-dataframe).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Could you clarify what the `t` variable is for?

Comment: it's just a temporary variable that, being the last one in the do block, is the one returned.