# Julia: Create summary values for column x for each unique value in column y of DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia

I would like to apply some functions such as mean and variance to column `x` of my `DataFrame` for each unique value in column `y`. I can imagine building a loop that manually subsets the `DataFrame` to accomplish my end but I am trying not to reinvent the wheel for something which is likely a common feature.

```
using DataFrames
mydf = DataFrame(y = [randstring(1) for i in 1:1000], x = rand(1000))
# I could imagine a function that looks like:
apply(function = mean, across = mydf[:x], by = mydf[:y])
```

Comment: `groupby` is your friend. Look at the example in the online-doc by typing `?groupby` in REPL (specifically example using `combine`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to collapse data with duplicate timestamps in Julia \`DataFrame\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756537/how-to-collapse-data-with-duplicate-timestamps-in-julia-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right this is very common.  Take a look at the [split-apply-combine](http://juliastats.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/split_apply_combine/#The-Split-Apply-Combine-Strategy-1) chapter in the documentation.  There are several approaches here: you can either use the more general `by` function to specify exactly what columns you want to operate over, or you can use the handy `aggregate` function to use all the other columns and automatically name them sensibly:

```
julia> aggregate(mydf, :y, mean)
62×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ y   │ x_mean   │
├─────┼─────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ "0" │ 0.454196 │
│ 2   │ "1" │ 0.541434 │
│ 3   │ "2" │ 0.36734  │
⋮
```