# Julia DataFrame: Create new column sum of col values :x by :y

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a `DataFrame` of x and y occurrences. I would like to count how often each occurrence happens in the `DataFrame` and what percentage of the `:y` occurrences that combination represents. I have the first part down now, thanks to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948804/julia-create-summary-values-for-column-x-for-each-unique-value-in-column-y-of-d).

```
using DataFrames
mydf = DataFrame(y = rand('a':'h', 1000), x = rand('i':'p', 1000))
mydfsum = by(mydf, [:x, :y], df -> DataFrame(n = length(df[:x])))
```

This successfully creates a column that counts how often each value of `:x` occurs with each value of `:y`. Now I need to be able to generate a new column that counts how often each value of `:y` occurs. I could next create a new `DataFrame` using:

```
mydfsumy = by(mydf, [:y], df -> DataFrame(ny = length(df[:x])))
```

Join the `DataFrames` together.

```
mydfsum = join(mydfsum, mydfsumy, on = :y)
```

And create the percentage `:yp` column

```
mydfsum[:yp] = mydfsum[:n] ./ mydfsum[:ny]
```

But this seems like a clunky workaround for a common data management problem. In R I would do all of this in one line using `dplyr`:

```
mydf %>% groupby(x,y) %>% summarize(n = n()) %>% groupby(y) %>% mutate(yp = n/sum(n))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one line:

`mydfsum = by(mydf, :y, df -> by(df, :x, dd -> DataFrame(n = size(dd,1), yp = size(dd,1)/size(df,1))))`

or, if that becomes hard to read, you can use the `do` notation for anonymous functions:

`mydfsum = by(mydf,:y) do df
    by(df, :x) do dd
        DataFrame(n = size(dd,1), yp = size(dd,1)/size(df,1))
    end
end`

What you are doing in R is actually doing a first `by` on both `x` and `y`, then mutating a column of the output. You can also do that, but you need to have created that column first. Here I first initialize the `yp` column with zeroes and then modify it in place with another `by`.

`mydfsum = by(mydf,[:x,:y], df -> DataFrame(n = size(df,1), yp = 0.))
by(mydfsum, :y, df -> (df[:yp] = df[:n]/sum(df[:n])))`

For more advanced data manipulation you may want to take a look at [Query.jl](https://github.com/davidanthoff/Query.jl)